# java binary message parsing

Tags: java, open-source, binary, message

Are there any good java libraries for parsing & dealing with proprietary messages in UDP size packets?  The message is a simple byte array, where each byte(s) represents enums or text/ascii values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a ByteBuffer to wrap your `byte[]`

Comment: Peter,  just curious what are the advantages of using the ByteBuffer vs. DataInputStream?  The DataInputStream appears to have methods for parsing & writing various types that will ultimately be mapped to fields of a POJO.

Comment: The ByteBUffer is re-usable. It supports ByteOrder (DataIn/Output is BigEndian only) It can be used with NIO. It has the option of using a direct ByteBuffer which is off heap.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read the type of data you want if it fits the conversions (i.e. when reading an int check the endianess used by DataNIputStream matches your platform), wrapped around a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) directly fed by your byte array.

Comment: this looks very promising, i will be trying this for sure!